# Regression with Time series model

Tags: regression, spss, stata

I wanted to see if the different kinds of supports to small enterprises have contributed to the development/growth of small enterprises  using 15 years period data (6 years before implementing these programs & 9 years after it). I used comparative research design & applied linear time series regression. At 10% significance level, the result gave me the following result:

```
            -R squared= 0.35, Adjusted R squared= -0.03    
            -some coefficients are positive & some are negative  
            -p-values for all the four independent variables' coefficients are >    
             significance level
            -t-stat= 0.5, 0.2, -0.2, & 1.4
```

Therefore,

1) How can I interpret these results? 
2) Can I use < 90% confidence interval to see at what % C.I. the support programs become significant to have effect on the growth? 
3) Am I expected to provide explanations as to why it is unusually negative or  insignificant? 
4) What type of tests should I conduct in this time series model? 
5) And finally, which software may I use- EVIEWS, SPSS or Stata?

You may answer all or any of these 5 questions. 
-Here is the data: -

```
No. of     credit      Training    marketing      Business             Organizing services
            (in $)     (in No of   services       development service    (in No. of firms)
                         Trainees) (in No.of firms)   (in No.of firms)
employees     

45,351    44,062,000    2,990    1,322          1,920                19,134              
107,283   109,560,000   40,435   30,662         5,353                74,941            
20,131    36,050,000    8,375    7,500          4,848                8,225       
64,945    83,600,000    16,538   18,779         7426                 6406
223,242   157,100,000   10,894   25,876         2479                 9909
134,611   229,912,620   33,547   58,687         6,642                27,971  
                                                                     39092
90,529    271,924,783   70,157   18,543         2,300                                  
63,759    368,691,717   12,148   12,443         3,954                67,238
110,619   491,586,029   76,461   25,414         4,168                70,600
```

Comment: You have a higher probability of getting helpful responses if you reduce the number of question- and exclamationmarks. As for interpretating the results; I think it would help if you could tell where the data came from, how the experiment was designed, etc.

Comment: The data is poorly formatted making it difficult (impossible) to understand. Could this please be fixed? I suggest formatting the data so that each variable has its own column and title header.

Comment: @Graeme Walsh The data given here appear to be background data. The original poster did not ever post any of the time series. My own instinct is to wonder whether 6 + 9 data points is very much for the time series analysis recommended elsewhere.

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for that useful information. It's a pity that the OP did not post any of the time-series as this may have helped the question receive some more activity and helpful answers. By the way, I also share your view with regard to the number of data points.

Answer (score 1):

Regression with time series is generally not advisable as there may be (will be) autocorrelation in the residuals.

When building a predictive model with time series data one needs to be concerned with

1. how many time trends (if any) are needed
2. how many (if any) level shifts are needed
3. what differencing is needed
4. what is the appropriate autoregressive lag structure (ARMA)
5. are there any outliers that need to be treated so that the model parameters are not impacted by the unusual
6. are the parameters constant over time
7. is the variance of the errors constant over time
8. is there a need to incorporate causal variables.

Post your data and your analysis for one of your data sets and I will report my results taking into account the above considerations.